# Import Swift into Objective-C - "use of undeclared identifier"

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I'm not able to import Swift class into Objective-C.

- Xcode version: 10.1
- Swift: 4.2

My steps:

1. Create empty Single-View Objective-C project called "test".
2. Create Swift class (mytestclass.swift)
3. Create bridging empty header "test-Swift.h"
4. Try to use in `ViewController.m` like this: `#import "test-Swift.h"
   [[MyTestClass init] calculate];`

### mytestclass.swift

```
import Foundation

@objc public class MyTestClass: NSObject {

    @objc public func calculate() {
        print("TEST")
    }
}
```

After compilation I get:

> /Users/xxx/Desktop/test/ViewController.m:19:7: Use of undeclared
>   identifier 'MyTestClass'

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in step

> 3- Create bridging empty header "test-Swift.h"

You shouldn't create that file manually , as it's created when you add the swift file to your Objective-C , also you need to replace this line

```
[[MyTestClass init] calculate];
```

with

```
[[[MyTestClass alloc] init] calculate];
```

or

```
[[MyTestClass new] calculate];
```

Here is a working  [demo](https://github.com/ShKhan9/SwifttObbb)

Comment: It doesn't work. It just can't see MyTestClass at all.

Comment: i created a demo check it

Comment: Thank you! It turned out that created manually file "test-Swift.h" causes this issue. So after skipping step 3. it works!